# find the frequency of a multi array

Tags: c++, arrays

problem:

> Given a matrix of integers, count the amount of times each number 0-9 appears. Print out your results on one line in the following form:
> `0:number of zeros;1:number of ones;2:number of twos;3:number of threes;4:number of fours;5:number of fives;6:number of sixes;7:number of sevens;8:number of eights;9:number of nines;`
> For example, if you are passed an identify matrix, it contains 12 zeros and 4 ones and no other numbers from 0 to 9, your output would be:

> `0:12;1:4;2:0;3:0;4:0;5:0;6:0;7:0;8:0;9:0;`

So far I have been created some codes:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void printfrequency(int array[][4])
{
    int c=0; 
    for(int a=0; a<10; a++){
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for ( int j=0;j<4;j++)
                if(array[i][j] == a){
                    c++;
                }
        cout << a << ":" << c <<";" ;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int array[4][4] = { {3,5,7,9}, {2,4,8,9},{1,1,1,1},{3,6,9,2} };
    printfrequency(array);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the ouput:

```
0:0;1:4;2:6;3:8;4:9;5:10;6:11;7:12;8:13;9:16;
```

How can I achieve `0:12;1:4;2:0;3:0;4:0;5:0;6:0;7:0;8:0;9:0;` ?

Comment: Habits to drop: including bits header, using namespace std, misindenting, confusing C and C++.

Comment: Please explain why you expect the specified output. What is the logic? If you can do that it will help finding the root of your problem. It will help you and help potential answerers.

Comment: Firstly, you can use hashing technique to count the occurrence. However, I am not sure the logic behind the output you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You are aware that the specified example output from the assignment cannot be the output from your code, even if and because the code is correct, aren't you?

Comment: thanks a lot, the only problem is the increment. in my code, the expect answer should be: ```0:0;1:4;2:2;3:2;4:1;5:1;6:1;7:1;8:1;9:3;```. but what this is what i  get i```0:0;1:4;2:6;3:8;4:9;5:10;6:11;7:12;8:13;9:16;```.

Comment: @HonghuiOuyang Are elements of the matrix always between 0 to 9?

Comment: @Ch3steR Possibly not, but that is not needed for the correct result because the goal is "count the amount of times each number 0-9 appears".

Comment: @Yunnosch Yeah maybe. If the digits were between 0-9. Instead of using nested for-loops, OP could get away with one for-loop for counting and one for printing with extra space, maybe an array of size 9.

Comment: @Yunnosch Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/qE8vWanPh .I don't know if this is relevant to the post so I'll just leave it as a comment. Your answer addresses OP's issue upvoted already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you show gives output based on the frequencies for the specific array init visible in the shown code.
That array init contains no zeros, so the output should start with "0:0"  and it does. (Actually required for the shown array init would be "zeros:0", but I stick with your codes basic concept of output and only discuss frequency values).
The output mentioned as example in the assignemnt is for an "identity" matrix, though you have a typo there. Such an identity matrix has a diagonal of "1"s in other wise all "0"s. Counting them gives the output of 4 ones and 12 zeros for a 4 by 4 matrix as shown.

The code is not correct, it fails to reset the count and the frequencies hence increase over the output.
To fix that mistake (but still get the frequencies for the array init, not the example output) change

```
int c=0; 
for(int a=0; a<10; a++)
{
```

to

```
for(int a=0; a<10; a++)
{
    int c=0;
```

That will reset the count for each digit your are counting and get you the output:

```
0:0;1:4;2:2;3:2;4:1;5:1;6:1;7:1;8:1;9:3;
```

Comment: Hi all the upvoters. I have changed "does and should 0:12" to "does and should 0:0". Fixing quite a relevant confusion in my answer. I hope you upvoted for the general problem explanation and not because you thought what I wrote before was correct.... I.e. I hope I get to keep your appreciated upvotes. If I made things worse now (because of being even more confused now than before) kindly explain.... Thanks either way.

Answer (score 1):

All answers are given, correct and accepted.

But additionally I would like to give some hints for a "better" C++ programming style.

We can see in your code that you maybe try to learn from some "Hacker" or "competition" site. That will never work. If you really want to learn C+, then start with books or serious sites.

What we can see in your code:

- `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is not compliant C++ code. The header file is an extension available for some compilers.But you should never use it.
- `using namespace std;` should never be used. Please use fully qualified names and to not pull in the complete `std::namespace`
- Prefer pre-increment overpost-increment, whereever possible
- Do not use C-Style arrays in C++. Use C++ instead.
- Variable names should be expressive
- Add comments. The more, the better.

Then, without changing any algorithm or structure of your original program and just modifying the names and adding comments, your code could look like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// We want to have a square matrix with 4 rows and 4 coulmns
constexpr unsigned int MatrixSize = 4;

// Save some typing work and make array definition more readable
using SquareMatrix = std::array<std::array<int, MatrixSize>, MatrixSize >;

// Function to print thr frequency of interges in a matrix in the range 0..9
void printFrequencyOfNumbersIn(SquareMatrix& squareMatrix) {

    // Check all interger digits in the range 0..9
    for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; ++digit) {

        // The initial counter value for this digit will always start with 0
        int digitCounterForThisDigit = 0;

        // Now, iterate over all rows
        for (int row = 0; row < MatrixSize; ++row)

            // And then iterate over all columns of that row
            for (int column = 0; column < MatrixSize; ++column)

                // CHeck, if the value in the matrix is equal to the current evaluated digit
                if (squareMatrix[row][column] == digit)

                    // If so, then increment counter
                    ++digitCounterForThisDigit;

        // And show the frequency count for the digit under evaluation
        std::cout << digit << ':' << digitCounterForThisDigit << ';';
    }
}

int main() {

    // Define and initialize our squre matrix
    SquareMatrix matrix = { {{3,5,7,9}, {2,4,8,9},{1,1,1,1},{3,6,9,2}} };

    // Let the subfunction analyze and print the frequencies
    printFrequencyOfNumbersIn(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

This is by far more better understandbale than the original version. Functionality wise it is the same.

---

And, if you want a "more modern" C++ approach, then you would use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. That is the idiomatic correct approach for frequency calculation.

This would then look like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using MyTpe = int;

// Save some typing work. This will define a square matrix with data of type T 
// and rows/columns size equal to template parameter MatrixSize
template <typename T,  size_t MatrixSize >
using SquareMatrix = std::array<std::array<T, MatrixSize>, MatrixSize>;

// Here we make an abbreviation for our square matrtx that should consist of 4 rows and 4 columns of ints
using MySquareMatrix = SquareMatrix<MyTpe, 4u>;


// Print frequency of any interger in the matrix
void printFrequencyOfNumbersin(MySquareMatrix& mySquareMatrix) {

    // Standard idiomatic approach for counting elements
    std::map<MyTpe, size_t> counter{ {0,0u}, {1,0u}, {2,0u}, {3,0u}, {4,0u}, {5,0u}, {6,0u}, {7,0u}, {8,0u}, {9,0u} };

    // Go through all rows and columns of the matrix
    for (const auto& row : mySquareMatrix) for (MyTpe columnValue : row)

        // Count occurence of cell value
        counter[columnValue]++;

    // Show result to user
    for (const auto [number, count] : counter) std::cout << number << ':' << count << ';';
}

int main() {
    // Test Data
    MySquareMatrix matrix = { {{3,5,7,9}, {2,4,8,9},{1,1,1,1},{3,6,9,2}} };

    // Evaluate and print
    printFrequencyOfNumbersin(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 
 int main(){
     map<int,int>mp;
      int array[4][4] = { {3,5,7,9},{2,4,8,9},{1,1,1,1},{3,6,9,2} };
      
      mp[0]=0,mp[1]=0, mp[2]=0,mp[3]=0, mp[4]=0,mp[5]=0,mp[6]=0,mp[7]=0,mp[8]=0,mp[9]=0;
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
          
          for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
             int x=array[j][i];
             mp[x]++;
             }
      }
       
      for(auto it=mp.begin();it!=mp.end();it++){
          cout<<it->first<<":"<<it->second<<";";
      }
       }
```

Comment: Everybody can do as he wants. But I would not recomend to somebody to use things like ```` #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;````  or C-Style arrays in C++. For printing, you could use structured bindings. But as said. Everybody does as he likes.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.